Suitability of ROX 2 / 4 for MTB trail use
I've been looking into getting a cheap bike computer to help me navigate. I've not been doing mountain biking long and would like to start exploring away from trail centres and marked trails and follow routes on the likes of Kamoot.
I've been looking at the Sigma ROX 2 or 4 as they seem to get decent reviews, however, most of the reviews I've read seem to be from road bikers. I've no interest in heart rate, cadence, etc, just the navigation.
My question is: are these suited for MTB-use on trails, and not roads, or should I be looking to spend more?

I use the ROX 4  for Gravel biking. The navigation works fine most of the time, but:

The GPS receiver is not very precise, particularly under tree cover. The device sometimes claims I'm "off track" as it thinks I'm 10-20m to the side of the trail. This is not a big issue for me, but it might be for you if you ride a dense trail network and can't determine whether you're on the right trail.
The minimalist display of the track (no background map) means it's sometimes hard to determine which turn to take. This is fine for road and gravel cycling where most turns are 90°, but if you frequently encounter irregular crossings with many paths going in odd angles, it might be impractical.

The question is mostly: How often do those issues arise and how bad is it to check your smartphone?
If...

you ride lonely trails with few (irregular) crossings, or without tree cover
don't mind checking your smartphone for detailed navigation a few times per ride

the ROX will be fine.
If you...

want to achieve high speeds and can't occasionally stop to double-check
ride a dense trail network with many odd crossings
can only spare short glances at the device (due to technical terrain) to thoroughly check out the track

the ROX probably isn't the right device for you.
Even for road/gravel cycling, the map display takes a little getting used to; with some practice, missed turns become rare but never fully disappear. IMO the ROX is pretty good for the price and perfectly fine for non-speed freaks. The minimalist approach has some advantages (little battery use, fast start-up, simple usage).
But you definitely also need to bring your smartphone with navigation app on a ride - navigation works autonomously without an active smartphone connection, but if you need to double-check a crossing or re-route your tour, you need the phone.

Thank you for such a thorough answer. These were the sort of things I was thinking about. I'm happy to put up with the limitations on a cheaper device if I know them before buying. Cheers!

@Erlkönig What is the approach when you need to recompute a route (because you need to shorten the ride or in case of road closures)? Can you generate it on the phone and upload the new route using Bluetooth?

@Renaud Same way as planning a new route - plan it in the Sigma app (pretty limited though), Kommot (recommended) or Strava or any app that can export GPX (unfortunately GPX import doesn't work great), and then transfer it via Bluetooth using the Sigma App.
